# Enterprise architect: Get center values of opened viewed diagram

Tags: scripting, diagram, enterprise-architect

I have open and active diagram in EA (15.2). And I want to get [x,y] position of viewed part of this diagram. The goal is to place class here by scripting (VBS).

Do you have any suggestion where is this information stored?

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean with the "viewed part"? The part of the diagram that is currently visible is not stored anywhere. The location of the existing elements can be found in the DiagramObjects

Comment: Thank you Geert. Yes I mean the visible part. I was afraid that it is not accessible. And what about visible elements - can be selected anyhow???

Comment: I need to create Diagram link, so the script is activated from Project browser and Diagram link is placed to open diagram, so I cannot simply select the elements on diagram.

Comment: No EA's API doesn't give you any information about the visible part of the diagram or the visible elements.

Comment: You could calculate the size from the diagram elements and hack Windoze to give you the slider positions of the current diagram window. Probably some hacking. Pretty sure that's doable, though I can't tell since I'm not a Windoze hacker. Anyhow I can confirm what Geert said: EA does not give you that.